# MySql querying columns properties

Tags: mysql, sql

My table looks like this.

```
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| Field           | Type     | Null | Key | Default | Extra |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
| start_date_time | datetime | NO   | PRI | NULL    |       |
| ch01            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch02            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch03            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch04            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch05            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch06            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch07            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch08            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch09            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch10            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch11            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch12            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch13            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch14            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch15            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch16            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch17            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
| ch18            | int(11)  | YES  |     | NULL    |       |
+-----------------+----------+------+-----+---------+-------+
```

I have this query.

```
select 
    @ch := 'ch01' as channel, 
    avg(ch01) as average, std(ch01) as std, 
    max(ch01) as max, min(ch01) as min 
from 
    (select ch01 
     from myTable/*This query is more complex, this is a simplified version just to keep things clear*/) as t1
union
select 
    @ch:='ch02' as channel, avg(ch02) as average, 
    std(ch02) as std, max(ch02) as max, min(ch02) as min 
from 
    (select ch02 
     from myTable/*Same here, this is a simplified version, same as the one above*/) as t2
union
....so on for the 18 channels i have.
```

The output looks like this.

```
+---------+----------+---------+------+------+
| channel | average  | std     | max  | min  |
+---------+----------+---------+------+------+
| ch01    | 244.9091 | 12.5514 |  265 |  223 |
| ch02    | 282.0909 | 22.1049 |  321 |  239 |
..............................................
+---------+----------+---------+------+------+
```

Is there a better approach to achieve the same output?

Comment: You are trying to `UNPIVOT` your table. As I know the recent version of MySQL have no `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT` function, so you have to use the `UNION` based solution.

Comment: "Is there a better approach to achive the same output?" Yes. See normalization.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

First of all consider to change your data model!

```
CREATE TABLE MyTable (
    channel VARCHAR(8),
    start_date_time TIMESTAMP,
    channelValue INT
)
```

(Add constraints and adjust the datatypes to your needs!)

**If you can not modify your model, then here is a solution:**

The thing, you are trying to do is called: `UNPIVOT`
Unfortunetly MySQL have no function like `PIVOT` and `UNPIVOT`. The workaround is the `UNION ALL` solution.

You can simplify your complex part by creating a subquery, than you can use aggregate function on the result of that subquery:

```
SELECT
    channel,
    AVG(channelValue)
    /* Add the additional aggregations here*/
FROM (
        SELECT 'ch01' as channel, start_date_time, ch01 AS channelValue FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ch02' as channel, start_date_time, ch02 FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ch03' as channel, start_date_time, ch03 FROM myTable
        UNION ALL
        /* ... */
        UNION ALL
        SELECT 'ch18' as channel, start_date_time, ch18 FROM myTable
    ) AS UPVT
GROUP BY
    channel
```

You can create a view based on the subquery and you can use it in your query

```
CREATE VIEW MyTableUnpivot AS
SELECT 'ch01' as channel, start_date_time, ch01 AS channelValue FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ch02' as channel, start_date_time, ch02 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ch03' as channel, start_date_time, ch03 FROM myTable
UNION ALL
/* ... */
UNION ALL
SELECT 'ch18' as channel, start_date_time, ch18 FROM myTable
```

Then you can use your new view:

```
SELECT
    channel,
    AVG(channelValue)
    /* Add the additional aggregations here*/
FROM MyTableUnpivot
GROUP BY
    channel
```